# Looking for a certain sentence that refers to "throughout time"

Tags: expressions, sentence

I am writing an essay and I'm trying to say how something has been understood since the beginning of time. I cannot remember the exact phrased use, but it relates to "throughout time" or "throughout generations". I am using it for this sentence: Murder is understood as being the most immoral tendency (throughout time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

> Murder has always been understood as the most immoral tendency.